# Safely Remove Hardware (USB drive) needs End Process for rundll32.exe - Windows XP SP3

Tags: windows-xp

```
Image Name                   PID Modules                                      
========================= ====== =============================================
rundll32.exe                 252 ntdll.dll, kernel32.dll, msvcrt.dll,         
                                 GDI32.dll, USER32.dll, IMAGEHLP.dll,         
                                 ShimEng.dll, AcGenral.DLL, ADVAPI32.dll,     
                                 RPCRT4.dll, Secur32.dll, WINMM.dll,          
                                 ole32.dll, OLEAUT32.dll, MSACM32.dll,        
                                 VERSION.dll, SHELL32.dll, SHLWAPI.dll,       
                                 USERENV.dll, UxTheme.dll, guard32.dll,       
                                 fltlib.dll, comctl32.dll, comctl32.dll,      
                                 NvMcTray.dll, SETUPAPI.dll, IMM32.dll,       
                                 nvapi.dll
```

I have to end the rundll32.exe process to safely remove my USB drive. Given the modules rundll32.exe is running, do you know which running module(s) would prevent the USB drive from being safely removed, and if so is there a more permanent straightforward solution such as changing an automatic service (the list from services.msc) into a disabled/manual service or maybe something else you can think of?

Comment: rundll32 is a "helper" process that is used to execute an arbitrary function in a DLL, to determine what this is, look to see what command line it was called with

Answer (score 1):

[Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) helps in such cases.

It tells you exactly which process is locking the drive and is (normally) able to unlock the process without terminating it.

This also works if a folder or a file cannot be renamed / moved / deleted for a similar reason.